# How to create a Multi-Option Lookup field in Power Apps Model driven app

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I’m new to Power Apps model driven app. Could you please guide me how to create a column which accepts multiple users from **User** Entity.

I have an **Account** Table in which there can be multiple owner.

As of now I have created a lookup field which accepts only one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check out this PCF Control: https://pcf.gallery/polylookup/

I've created this control with more advanced features compared to other available controls in PCF Gallery such as supporting N:N and custom N:N relationships, dynamic filtering, quick create, and more.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Last time when I checked this multi-select lookup control was [available only in Dynamics 365 Field service module](https://byrondittberner.com/2022/04/13/how-to-configure-a-multiselect-lookup-in-dynamics-365/). Eventually it should be available in all Dataverse but not right away.

Meantime we can use this [PCF control](https://pcf.gallery/multiselect-records/).